# not selector isn't working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Very simple piece of code which I think should be working. Slightly confused as to why it isn't.

I have an arrow with the class 'right', when you click it the year variable ticks up. When a certain year is reached this div also is given the class 'dead', I want this to kill the click function, so I added the 'not' selector as a condition of the click function. However, the year continues to tick up when you click the button.

Any ideas?

[Try clicking the blue bar](http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/satisfaction2015/index.html) to the right with your console open to see the result

```
$('.right').not('.dead').click(function(){
    year += 1;
    console.log(year);
    if (year === 2015){
        $(this).addClass('dead');
    }
});
```

Comment: create a fiddle for this

Comment: Click handler added before `class` added ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$('.right').not('.dead')` part of your code is evaluated only once; not each time one of them is clicked.

You could try something like the following instead:

```
$('.right').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('dead')) { return; }
    year += 1;
    console.log(year);
    if (year === 2015){
        $(this).addClass('dead');
    }
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I don't know anything about this return function but clearly stops the rest of the function from running. Will look into it.

Answer (score 3):

You created a binding that doesn't exist when the page is loaded, so what you need to do instead is use the event delegation syntax of `.on()` to handle dynamically added events. Change your selector from:

```
$('.right').not('.dead').click(function(){
```

to:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.right:not(".dead")' ,function () {
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/onnzm8oh/1)**

Answer (score 2):

The not is only working as an initial filter for what to bind on, not being continually checked to see if the bind event should be processed.

Answer (score 0):

If the .dead class has not been added when:

```
$('.right').not('.dead')
```

is called it will attach those events to all those elements. It will not continue to check against them later to make sure those elements don't have that class. You will need to remove the event when the .dead class is added.